# How to install modules on a mac

Tags: python

I install modules on my mac and then I install with pip again and it says requirement satisfied e.g pip install pygame.

I go into pycharm and it comes up with saying Error-Module not found, I install in the pycharm terminal and it shows requirement satisfied and it still says Module cannot be found and its really annoying me. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you know if you've installed multiple versions of Python? This seems like two versions of python are conflicting with each other.

Comment: It's possible to have more than one version of Python installed.  It sounds like you're installing `pygame` for one version of python, but PyCharm is using a different version.

Comment: How do you check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is probably is that your IDE is using a different python interpreter from that you're installing your modules on.
try the following:
in your terminal, where you install modules using pip, go with `python --version` and see what it shows. then go to Pycharm > preferences > project > project interpreter. and make sure it's the same or change to desired one.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, however, since then I've switched to windows, which has helped me greatly and now I have no problems!